# How to store and retrieve YouTube embed in MySQL database with PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, youtube

I am trying to store and retrieve the HTML of an embedded YouTube video on my site but am running into trouble. Here is my code:

`Controller`

```
$html = request('media');

$html = htmlentities($html);

$post = Post::create(array_merge(['media' => $html],request(['title', 'content'])));
```

`Retrieval`

```
{{ html_entity_decode($post->media) }}
```

Important things to mention, I am using Laravel, and in my MySQL database, I am storing this HTML as the type `text`. So, how would I accomplish this? The retrieval code simply shows the HTML code but does not render. When I look at the source, it is because the HTML retrieved looks like this

```
&lt;iframe width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;315&quot; src=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/CgsymJy0RJk&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allow=&quot;autoplay; encrypted-media&quot; allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

How do I save this HTML into my database so I can retrieve it and it renders the embedded video that I would like it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On controller remove `$html = htmlentities($html);`

on view:
`{!! $post->media !!}`

Comment: @hoolakoola `htmlentities` is replacing your html tags with the code used to generate them. So your `"` becomes `&quot;` and `<` becomes `&lt;`. Laravel attempts to sanitise your outputs by default to prevent "second order" attacks, so by adding the `!!` inside your brackets, you are telling Laravel not to try and sanitise this output.

Comment: Thank you! So am I putting myself at any sort of risk by using `!!` inside the brackets? If I am the only one with permissions to add to the database?

Comment: As long as there is no way for someone to add malicious code to your database, it should be okay. It's normal practice to assume all data you add AND take out of the database is insecure. Perhaps a smart guy figures a way to make your app fetch the youtube embed code, but then also append some nasty javascript - your database wouldn't be affected, but then once someone views that video, they could be at risk.

Comment: _“Awesome thank you, can you explain why this works?”_ - should you really be working with Laravel already, if you lack the absolute basic knowledge when it comes to topics like this …?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use function `htmlentities` which change the code you save in the database:

As written  in [**PHP** manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

> htmlentities — Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities

In addition, be aware of *SQL-injections* when save raw HTML in the database.

OR just use `html_entity_decode` in controller after read media from DB.